How to print a RichTextBox's contents with formatting, margins and pictures?
I have a text editor WinForms application. When I try to print (as in with a printer, not in a console) the contents of a RichTextBox in VB.NET, it does, but without formatting, margins and it does not automatically go to the next line when hitting the edge of the page.
Here's how I'm doing it right now:
**PrintDocument1_PrintPage**

`Dim usedFont As Font = RichTextBox1.Font
Dim txtWidth As Integer = PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Width - PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left - PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right
Dim stringSize As New SizeF

Dim g = Me.CreateGraphics

lstLinesToPrint.Clear()

For intCounter = 0 To RichTextBox1.Lines.Count - 1
    stringSize = g.MeasureString(RichTextBox1.Lines(intCounter), usedFont)
    If stringSize.Width < txtWidth Then
        lstLinesToPrint.Add(RichTextBox1.Lines(intCounter))
    Else
        Dim LeftMargin As Integer = PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left
        Dim TopMargin As Integer = PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top
        Dim sfBuffer As SizeF = g.MeasureString("M", usedFont)
        Dim layOutRec As New RectangleF(LeftMargin, TopMargin, txtWidth - sfBuffer.Width, usedFont.Height)
        Dim string_format As New Drawing.StringFormat
        string_format.Trimming = StringTrimming.Word
        Dim CharactersFitted As Integer = 0
        Dim LinesFilled As Integer = 0

        For intFittedChar = 0 To RichTextBox1.Lines(intCounter).Length - 1
            g.MeasureString(RichTextBox1.Lines(intCounter).Substring(intFittedChar), usedFont, New SizeF(layOutRec.Width, layOutRec.Height), string_format, CharactersFitted, LinesFilled)
            lstLinesToPrint.Add(RichTextBox1.Lines(intCounter).Substring(intFittedChar, CharactersFitted))
            intFittedChar += CharactersFitted - 1
        Next
    End If
Next`


**PrintDocument1_BeginPrint**

`Static intStart As Integer
Dim usedFont As Font = RichTextBox1.Font
Dim txtHeight As Integer
Dim LeftMargin As Integer = PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left
Dim RightMargin As Integer = PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right
Dim TopMargin As Integer = PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top
txtHeight = PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Height - PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top - PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom

Dim LinesPerPage As Integer = CInt(Math.Round(txtHeight / (usedFont.Height + 0.025)))

e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, e.MarginBounds)
Dim intLineNumber As Integer

For Intcounter = intStart To RichTextBox1.Lines.Count - 1
    e.Graphics.DrawString(RichTextBox1.Lines(Intcounter), usedFont, Brushes.Black, LeftMargin, usedFont.Height * intLineNumber + TopMargin)
    intLineNumber += 1
    If intLineNumber > LinesPerPage - 1 Then
        intStart = Intcounter
        e.HasMorePages = True
    End If
Next`


You're supposed to search for similar questions before posting a new one. This question addresses your issue. You just need to convert the code to VB from C#. If you have issues with that, ask an appropriate question about that specifically. Note that posting all the C# code and asking others to convert it for you is not an appropriate question.

Hello, thanks for this precision. However, I have absolutely no knowledge of C#, and I am therefore unable to convert this code. Furthermore, you asked not to create a topic about converting the code, which is understandable, and suggested that I make one for translating in general. I do not understand how such a post could take form (what I am allowed to ask or not), as I am pretty new to this forum.

C# and VB are often almost identical, so translation often involves little more than removing a semicolon. Some parts may be more complex but all the principles will be the same so you can probably do most of it yourself with a bit of effort. As I said, for the parts you can't do yourself, you can ask a specific question. Have you even looked at the code? It's a class, a few structures and some methods. I suspect that you can do that in VB. Again, you won't be able to do it all yourself but you won't know what you can't do until you actually try.
